# TypeError: Type is not callable in my code

Tags: solidity, remix, data-types

I started learning solidity, and I try to make a basic contract that add stocks to specific addresses. Here it is:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract faya{
    
    holders[] public investors;
    
    mapping(address=>uint256)  public addressToStock;
    mapping(address=>bool)  public addressinvests;

    struct holders{
        address _address;
    }

   

 function deposit(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
    if (addressinvests(_address)==false){
        investors.push(holders(_address));
        addressToStock[_address]=_value;
                                        }


      if (addressinvests(_address)==true){
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]+_value;
                                        }
    
    
                                                            }

    function withdraw(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]-_value;
        investors[_address]-=_value;
    }}
```

When I compile in remix, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Type is not callable
> --> faya coin.sol:20:9:
> |
> 20 |     if (addressinvests(_address)==false){
> |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because `addressinvests` is a mapping, so your semantic for calling the value is incorrect.

Change `addressinvests(_address)` to `addressinvests[_address]`

…also, your naming convention for the mapping is odd considering status quo. I’d advise `addressInvests`

Comment: Thanks. It works now, and I will take your naming suggestion into my coding in the future.